# Gives the distance between the fixed elements and table elements - print mode

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I was try to make a printable report...

The report form was i made is messed up at the second page...

So i think i should try a simple experience..

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panji123/L2e2n3rp/) and result same mess thing.

I have a fixed element ( for logo , slogan , ect ) and a dynamic table . i give the distance it with `<body style="padding-top: 25mm;">` but only the first page that work , another page is not working ( the fixed element and dynamic table doesn't have distance ).

I have try `@page{ padding: 50mm 0mm 50mm 0mm;}` but `padding` didn't work. `margin` is work but that make the fixed element is croped ! ( when i used `style="margin-top:-50mm;` )

Page 1 :

[image]

Page 2 :

[image]

as you see `<body style="padding-top: 25mm;">` only work for page 1.

how to give padding on page 2 ?

thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

just include a `background color` to your first table to get this fixed!!

**HTML**

```
    <table style="border: none;position: fixed;top: 0;margin-top: 0px; background:#ffffff;z-index:1;">
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color: black;color: white;width: 64px;text-align: center;">
         LOGO
      </td>
      <td>
         abcdefghj
         <br/> bnbkas jbkasb jkbsa jbkjas bkjsbk
         <br/> csfajkfsaj 4812-4124-4124
         <br/> dfsafsfsaf <a href=""> sagasg@asgasgsag.rsaf </a>        
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top:50px; position:absolute; top:50px;">
   <tr>
      <td> no </td>
      <td> nama </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 3 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 4 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 6 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 8 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 11 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 13 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 14 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 8 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 11 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 13 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 14 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 13 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 14 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 8 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 11 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 13 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 14 </td>
      <td> nama tes </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7b66aun1/)

Comment: It just make the background to white , it doesn't give any distance.